# Data Usage by Apps That Aren't Running

Tags: data-monitoring

I have a OnePlus 3 and am using a product called GlassWire to monitor my data activity.  Recently it is showing that certain of my apps are using the network even though they are not running.  By this I don't mean not running in the foreground, I mean they're not started at all.

Could someone explain how this could be?

If you need me to be more specific about anything please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not explaining how this can be vividly, but background processes do sometimes connect to data. You can use [DataEye](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lotusflare.datasensor). I've been using this app. It helps control data usage and blocks unwanted background data.

Answer (score -1):

Restrict background data for those apps..

Comment: Thank you, however I know how to restrict data usage for the apps.  My question was, why is it necessary if the app isn't running at all?  Can an app start up spontaneously without my knowledge?  Why would it do that surreptitiously?  btw, this isn't a background process, it's a process that isn't running.

Comment: @PAnderson Apps have background process or services! So even if you don't lunch them, they keep running. Example: How does a mail client fetch new mails even if you don't open it?

Comment: Thank you.  I guess it was sort of a "duh" question.  I also now see the option in Developer Options to see the services and processes that are currently running (turns out pretty much everything).